# Can we populate single dropdown with two tables data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to know how to:

1>Create a custom List with data from two tables
Data is stored in database in city and location tables both. Now, i want to populate dropdown with city name and location name both.

2> suppose it is done, then how to make distinction that it is city id or location id because on city name selection, i want city id column to be updated and on location selection, location id is to be updated in the same table on post action.

3>If it is not possible to make distinction between whose id to be updated then is it possible to populate dropdown with grouping such that in first group, only city name and in second group, only location name. something like this in this post https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/grouping-data-with-linq-and-mvc.html i was reading this article to get a clue how to use it in my dropdown.

Please help me out. I have seen almost all the stack overflow posts but doesnot get it how to do it.Right now, i am able to populate dropdown with single table in this way:

```
     public static List<City> allCity()
     {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return db.Cities.ToList();
        }
     }
```

and in controller, sending this list with the help of viewbag like this:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(allCity(), "Id", "CityName");
        return View();
     }
```

and on view page, like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Cities", ViewBag.CityId as SelectList, "Select a City")
```

Please Please someone tell me how to do it.

Comment: u r right sir but for me, it is still like something i have never done before so need some more help with some kind of code @musefan

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to set the `value` of the dropdown to be a custom format that you can then parse to see what type it is. One suggestion is to prefix the `id` with a letter to denote the type. For example: `C23` or `L46`

Have a model which contains the two lists and a property for the select value:

```
class MyModel
{
     public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
     public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
     public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

So in your view you can create the list like so:

```
<select id="SelectedValue" name="SelectedValue">
@foreach(var city in Model.Cities)
{
    <option value="C@(city.ID)">@(city.Name)</option>
}
@foreach(var location in Model.Locations)
{
    <option value="L@(location.ID)">@(location.Name)</option>
}
</select>
```

Then when you receive the value back in your controller you can do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    char inputType = model.SelectedValue[0];
    int id = int.Parse(model.SelectedValue.Substring(1));

    if(inputType == 'C')
    {
        // Insert City id.
    }
    else
    {
        // Insert Location id.
    }
}
```

Comment: what if he uses data annotation attributes for validation?

Comment: @GeneR: Can't imagine there is much validation to do on a dropdown, but I guess the default might be null and a selection is required. I believe you can still use a `ListID` property in the model and have the validation attribute on that, and then just make sure the `id/name` of the `select` element matches `ListID` property

Comment: this is pure html control , will it work? will it update controller's value should i have to create a view model to send data to view page ?? what about controller what should be there ?? @musefan

Comment: It all ends up as "pure html" anyway. The `name` is used to determine which form field the value represents. You can create a ViewModel yeah, prob easier to access the lists that way. Or you can get the value in the controller using `Request.Form["name_of_select"];`. It would be far too much for me to include all this in my answer, my answer assumes you have a working knowledge off passing data back and forth between view and controller

Comment: @musefan thnk u very much sir i think it should work i will try asap actually i was confused about html control will it work with mvc